# the understanding of $Z[i]/(2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have to proof that $Z[i]/(2)$ is not a field.
Am I right thinking that $Z[i]/(2)=\{0, 1, i, 1+i\}$?
Thanks!

Comment: You most certainly *did* write down a section (a set-theoretical one: it is by no means a homomorphism) of the canonical projection map.

Comment: Yes. I meant a set equivalent. So am I right?

Answer (score 1):

$1+i$ is a zero divisor.   So it's not an integral domain,  hence not a field.

Btw:  $(2)\subsetneq (2,1+i)=(1+i)\subsetneq\mathbb Z[i]$, hence $(2)$ isn't maximal...

Comment: As far as I can see, $(2,i)=\mathbb{Z}[i]$, as $i$ is invertible.

Comment: @egreg oh yeah.  How bout $(2,1+i)$?

Comment: That's much better; $(2,1+i)=(1+i)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right, in the sense that one can see what you mean. But this is not quite mathematically correct yet (what exactly is the induced structure on the set that you have written?).

Hint: a way to prove that $\Bbb Z[i]/(2)$ is a field is to prove that $(2)$ is maximal.

Comment: I think you may have meant $\;i\;$ instead of that $\;X\;$ there...

Comment: Sorry for the mistake in the task. I have to proof it is not a field. and I think its quite easy as: $(1+i)(1+i)=1+(i)^2+2i=1-1=0$

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly observe that $(1+i+(2))^2=1+2i-1+(2)=(2)$, so the ring would have a nonzero nilpotent element, *provided* you show that
$$
1+i\notin(2)
$$
However, if $2z=1+i$, then $|2z|^2=|1+i|^2$, that is, $2|z|^2=1$, a contradiction because $|z|^2$ is an integer.

In another way, you can observe that $2=(1+i)(1-i)$ and neither factor is invertible. Thus $2$ is not irreducible, hence not prime, so $(2)$ is not a prime ideal.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Z[i]\cong \mathbb Z[x]/(x^2+1) $, so $\mathbb Z[i]/(2) \cong \mathbb Z[x]/(2,x^2+1) \cong \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x^2+1)\cong \mathbb Z_2[x]/(x+1)(x-1)\cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2 $